How to Substitute a Metric into a Variation of the Action in Mathematica to Obtain Field Equations?
I have already calculated the variation of an action for a modified gravitational theory, and now I want to substitute a specific metric (e.g., the Schwarzschild metric) into this variation in Mathematica to obtain the corresponding field equations.
I would like to know if there is an efficient way to do this in Mathematica. Are there any recommended workflows, packages, or functions that can help me simplify this substitution process?
The code I have:
<<xAct`xCoba`
Quiet@Block[{Print},
<<xAct`xTras`
]
?DefManifold
DefManifold[M4,4,{\[Alpha],\[Beta],\[Sigma],\[Mu],\[Nu],a,b,c,d,e,f,h}]
DefMetric[-1,g[-\[Alpha],-\[Beta]],CD,PrintAs->"g"(*,FlatMetric\[Rule]True*)]
DefScalarFunction/@{A,B};
DefChart[BS,M4,{0,1,2,3},{t[],r[],\[Theta][],\[Phi][]},ChartColor->Red]

MatrixForm[MatrixBS=DiagonalMatrix[{-B[r[]],A[r[]],r[]^2,r[]^2*Sin[\[Theta][]]^2}]]
variationAction = \[Gamma] RicciCD[-a, -b]-1/2 \[Gamma] g[-a, -b] RicciScalarCD[]

